# Onclick function "is not defined"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am fairly new to wordpress and am trying to define and call a function but cannot get it to work.

The following code appears in a php file that is called from the content.php file using get_template_part.

```
<div onclick="checkAllTopicCheckBoxes()"> </div>
```

I added the following code to the bottom of the function.php file:

```
function checkAllTopicCheckBoxes() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

When I click the element it returns:

> (index):363 Uncaught ReferenceError: checkAllTopicCheckBoxes is not defined.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: It is about placement of your function!

Comment: is this checkAllTopicCheckBoxes function on the same script file or different file?

Comment: Add your code to the top of the file

Comment: I just cut and pasted the function to end of `js` file  and it worked.

Answer (score 15):

Using OnClick or similar attributes is very poor practice.

Using Javascript Event Listener is a much better way of doing this.
Registering an event in a modern way is the [unobtrusive way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) of handling events. Also to register more than one event listener for the target you can call addEventListener() for the same target.

HTML:

```
<div id="checkAllTopicCheckBoxes"> </div>
```

Your JavaScript is supposed to look like this:

```
document.getElementById ("checkAllTopicCheckBoxes").addEventListener ("click", myFunction, false);

function myFunction() {
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

**HTML attribute** (such as Onclick) should be avoided as it concerns the content/structure and behavior are not well-separated, making a bug harder to find.

Comment: @srMarquinho please do not switch US English spellings to UK English or vice versa.

Comment: How is the bug harder to find? To me, if I can use the, "Inspect Element" and debug by clicking the element.. then I can see easiest the function attached to the onclick. Go to the code, and perform a search for that function name, and there I am... Not sure why many say using onClick is bad practice.

Comment: Does not answer the question

Comment: People who automatically claim "onclick=" is bad practice... are like people who have an allergic reaction if you mention the "static" keyword in OOP.  They are entrenched in opinions taken as gospel, even though functional programming has shown that their opinions are arguably wrong and context is everything. Don't be deceived by programming paradigm zealots.

Comment: So what? the OP is not asking about best practices.

Comment: This answer is helpful, but the opinion that "using onclick" is poor practice is ridiculous. It assumes that the web app will have lots of JS code and can easily register event handlers with `addEventListener` calls. This is not the case. When you have a conventional web app with HTML generated on the server-side, it's usual to have `onclick`, etc. everywhere, and no dynamic event handler registration is really needed.

Answer (score 4):

What you wrote is a Javascript function, it must be surrounded by  in HTML code. Have you written your function in something like:

```
echo('<script>function checkAllTopicCheckBoxes() { alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");}</script>');
```

Also, I think Wordpress must have some function ready to use to add scripts. Try to have a look on [wp_enqueue_script (string $handle, string $src = false, array $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, bool $in_footer = false);](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)

**edit: I just found that question, it may answer yours: [How to write a Javascript function inside the functions.php of Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587280/how-to-write-a-javascript-function-inside-the-functions-php-of-wordpress)**

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same error like you.

If we use the onclick html attribute, we need to define that onclick function within the same html element (by using  tags).

It is best practice to create click event listener using javascript/jquery, than using onclick html attribute.

Comment: this isn't an answer

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your JavaScript function is defined above the html element which is calling that method :

```
<script>
function checkAllTopicCheckBoxes() 
{
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
</script>

<div onclick="checkAllTopicCheckBoxes()"> </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried this and my browser still complains that the function is "not defined."

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkAllTopicCheckBoxes() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

must be not in `<? ... ?>` and must have `<script>...</script>` wrap, e.g.,

```
======== sample.php =======
<? 
// php script is here
?>

<script>
function checkAllTopicCheckBoxes() {
  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
</script>
```

or if you want to include js inside php script, you must `echo` it like this

```
======== sample.php =======
<? 
// php script is here

echo '<script>';
echo 'function checkAllTopicCheckBoxes() {';
echo '  alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");';
echo '}';
echo '</script>';

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

this is also throw error if onclick function write inside jquery

```
<script>
   function onclick(){this right} 

    $(document).ready(function(){
        function onclick(){
           this is wrong
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).