# onclick function getInc not defined

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating my first web app and have run in to an issue pretty early on!

I have created a function which extracts the information that the user keys into the HTML input field. The way it should work is that when the user enters their income and clicks the submit button, the income is stored in a variable for me to use throughout the rest of my JavaScript code.
Looking at the console log, the function is coming up as 'not defined'.

I appreciate the code is probably not very clean but I just want to get it working as it's my first small project!

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row input-1">           
    <label for="Gross Annual Salary">£</label>
    <input type="number" name="Gross Annual Salary" id="Ann-Sal" placeholder="Gross Annual Salary" required>
    <input type="button" class="submit-btn" value="Submit" onclick="getInc();">                                              
</div>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
function getInc() {
    var inc = document.getElementById("Ann-Sal");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Onclick function "is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38051376/onclick-function-is-not-defined)

Comment: You have to make sure that the JavaScript runs AFTER the HTML has been parsed into memory. The best way to do that is to place your `script` tag just before the closing `body` tag (`</body>`).

Comment: Most likely the problem is with how your javascript and HTML are linked. Where is your <script> tag in your HTML file? Can you post it here?

Comment: @ScottMarcus does the position matter in this case? The value of `onclick` won't be resolved until a click actually occurs. By that point, `getInc` should be defined no matter where the script tag is. My guess is that it's an external js file and it's actually failing to load

Comment: There is a semicolon in your html at onclick=„getInc()“ this should not be there

Answer (score 0):

I remove semiclon from onclick end and it works

```html
<div class="row input-1">
  <label for="Gross Annual Salary">£</label>
  <input type="number" name="Gross Annual Salary" id="Ann-Sal" placeholder="Gross Annual Salary" required>
  <input type="button" class="submit-btn" value="Submit" onclick="getInc()">
</div>


<script>
  function getInc() {
    console.log('works');
    var inc = document.getElementById("Ann-Sal");
  }
</script>
```

```html
<script>
  function getInc() {
    console.log('works');
    var inc = document.getElementById("Ann-Sal");
  }
</script>

<div class="row input-1">
  <label for="Gross Annual Salary">£</label>
  <input type="number" name="Gross Annual Salary" id="Ann-Sal" placeholder="Gross Annual Salary" required>
  <input type="button" class="submit-btn" value="Submit" onclick="getInc()">
</div>
```

Comment: The semi-colon makes no difference here. Your answer assumes that the `script` element comes after the HTML and that's most likely not the case, hence the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have your `<script>` after the body (ie: put it after the last closing `<div>`), secondly if you want to what the user typed in you should get the elements value. When you set `inc` equal to `document.getElementById("Ann-Sal");` you are giving it the DOM element instead of the it's value instead you should put:

```
function getInc() {
    var inc = document.getElementById("Ann-Sal");
}
```

Then you will get the value the user inputted to the code.

Also, a tip use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of the onclick attribute, it's better practice.

Comment: No you don't need to remove the semi-colon.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Fixed.

Comment: The script tag should not be AFTER the `body`. It should be JUST BEFORE the closing `body` tag. Please take care with the wording in your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I tried to fix it myself using some of Tom O's code above here:

```
var buttonEl = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');

var inputEl = document.getElementById("Ann-Sal");

var annInc;

function clickHandler() {

    annInc = parseFloat(inputEl.value);
    console.log(annInc);
}

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row input-1">

                        <label for="Gross Annual Salary">£</label>
                        <input type="number" name="Gross Annual Salary" id="Ann-Sal" placeholder="Gross Annual Salary" required>
                        <input type="button" class="submit-btn" value="Submit">


                    </div>
```

This didn't work. There was no error message but nothing was logged to the console when submitting an income into the input field.

I then reconfigured the Javascript code to this:

```
var buttonEl = document.querySelector('input[type="button"]');

var inputEl = document.getElementById("Ann-Sal");

var annInc;

function clickHandler() {
    if (!inputEl.value.length) {
        console.error('A salary is required!');
        return;
    }

    annInc = parseFloat(inputEl.value);

    console.log(annInc);
}

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

This then worked. I didn't use the if statement to validate the users input previously because I used 'required' in the input element within my HTML code which basically does the same thing right? So i'm guessing the reason why the code wasn't working because the 'return' statement wasn't used?

Would someone be kind enough to explain to me why the return statement enabled this to work?

I'm sure for some of you experienced guys, my lack of understanding must be painful for you! I am super determined to get my head around this though.

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Besides the other answers, I just wanna point it out that is missing the `.value` in your function, otherwise, you won't get the value.

```
function getInc() {
    var inc = document.getElementById("Ann-Sal").value
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all you help guys, will try your suggestions tomorrow and let you know how I get on. It’s great to see all the helpful responses I’ve got though so thanks a lot!