# Tizen TAU Change Page - Javascript and other options like onload not working after Page Change (Wearable V5.5)

Tags: javascript, tizen

I've a projekt with a few different HTML Pages. If i switch the page with the `tau.changePage('second.html');`
Buttons and other stuff can't find the functions declared on the same html document. But it's possible to call javascript functions from other files or definied on the index.html.

I've tried it with the main project and an empty project which only includes two sites with a button on each side. See below. Do i've to manually set the focus on the new html site? The function test() gets this error:

> file:///second.html (1) :Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Basic</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (-tizen-geometric-shape: circle)" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.circle.min.css">
    <!-- load theme file for your application -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-page ui-page-active" id="main">
        <header class="ui-header">
            <h2 class="ui-title">TAU Basic</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="ui-content ui-content-padding">
            <p>Hello! </p>
            <button class="ui-btn" id="btn" onclick="changepage()">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lowBatteryCheck.js"></script>
    <script src="js/circle-helper.js"></script>
    <!--  <script src="./lib/tau/mobile/js/tau.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    <script>
    function changepage()
    {
        tau.changePage('second.html');
    };
    </script>
</body>



<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Basic2</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.min.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (-tizen-geometric-shape: circle)" href="lib/tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.circle.min.css">
    <!-- load theme file for your application -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="ui-page ui-page-active" id="second">
        <header class="ui-header">
            <h2 class="ui-title">TAU Basic</h2>
        </header>
        <div class="ui-content ui-content-padding">
            <p>Hello! </p>
            <button class="ui-btn" id="btn" onclick="test()">Test</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="lib/tau/wearable/js/tau.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lowBatteryCheck.js"></script>
    <script src="js/circle-helper.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="./lib/tau/mobile/js/tau.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    <script>
    function test()
    {
        console.log("test");
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be the order of the function definition and the call of the function. In your onclick event listener you referenced a function which is defined later, therefore you receive the ReferenceError.

It is usally a better practice to separate HTML, CSS and JavaScript from each other into their own files and link them together. Of course very simple examples can be an exception to this practice.

With that said, you should avoid event listeners in your markup and do that in your JavaScript files instead. [Please see this SO answer to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38051820/10301875).

I assume your app.js holds your logic. You can extract the test function into that file and do it like this:

```
const nextButton = document.getElementById("btn");
nextButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    test();
});

function test() {
    console.log("test");
}
```

You should now see "test" in the console when you change the page?

Best Regards

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem on my main project was that i included the ./lib/tau/mobile/js/tau.js more than one time. So it seems that it generated more than one page stack. And i had to move my script tag with the function into the main div. Now it works. 

PS: In the main project, the other functions are already in different .js files :)

Best Regards